# Getting WordPress on an Nginx proxy to work with a subdirectory

Tags: docker, nginx, wordpress, docker-compose

I'm trying to use the WordPress official Docker container to serve content from `https://example.com/blog`. An Nginx instance sits in front of WordPress and handles all the SSL-ishness. Nginx is configured like this:

```
upstream example-blog {
        server 127.0.0.1:4000 fail_timeout=30s;
}

...
server {
        server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
                proxy_connect_timeout   300;
                proxy_send_timeout      300;
                proxy_read_timeout      300;
                send_timeout            300;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server      $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
                proxy_pass              http://example-server;
        }

        location /blog {
                proxy_connect_timeout   300;
                proxy_send_timeout      300;
                proxy_read_timeout      300;
                send_timeout            300;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server      $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
                proxy_pass              http://example-blog;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = example.com {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

There is a Python Flask instance that serves locations under `/` (this works fine).

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <redacted>
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: <redacted>

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     build: .
     ports:
       - "127.0.0.1:4000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: <redacted>
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
                               define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com/blog');
                               define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/blog');
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM wordpress:latest

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

`docker-entrypoint.sh` is the one from the stock wordpress image, with this added:

```
if [[ ! -z ${WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA+x} ]]; then
        sed -i -e "/stop editing/i ${WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA//$'\n'/\\n}" wp-config.php
fi
```

to make it use the content of `WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA` in `wp-config.php` as the documentation (falsely) claims it does.

On first starting it all up and trying to access `example.com/blog`, I get redirected to `https://example.com/blog/wp-admin/install.php`, which then hits a redirect loop.  According to Firefox, that HTTPS address redirects to itself, and indeed `docker logs wordpress_wordpress_1` turns up a big pile of these:

```
172.27.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2020:17:15:41 +0000] "GET /blog/wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.0" 302 349 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0"
```

So this is not a problem of requests ping-ponging between nginx's HTTP handler and wordpress; it is wordpress returning redirects to itself.

Can someone point me towards how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your location blocks try

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
```

`$host` normally equals `$http_host`, except when $host equals the value of the server_name directive of the server which processed the request - and is different (i.e. regex) ([What's the difference of $host and $http_host in Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414810/whats-the-difference-of-host-and-http-host-in-nginx))

In your WordPress config, make sure you set the SSL http header on `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';`

Answer (score 0):

To initialize [*Wordpress*](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) in a subdirectory like `/blog`, you can use the `working_dir` attribute.

The default [*Wordpress*](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) image uses `/var/www/html` as *root*, and you can move to `/var/www/html/blog` to initialize at this point.

```yaml
# ...
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:apache
    working_dir: /var/www/html/blog
    volumes:
      - ./data/blog:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content
      - ./blog/wp-config.php:/var/www/html/blog/wp-config.php
# ...
```

Now, you can navigate to http://localhost/blog.

### Full example

Following is a full `docker-compose.yml` example:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

x-wordpress: &wordpress
  depends_on:
    - db
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  working_dir: /var/www/html/blog
  volumes:
    - wp_root:/var/www/html/blog
    - ./wp-content/plugins:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins
    - ./wp-content/themes:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/themes
    - ./wp-content/uploads:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/uploads
    - ./wp-content/languages:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/languages

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./backup/blog.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql:ro
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    <<: *wordpress
    image: wordpress:apache
    ports:
      - 80:80

  wpcli:
    <<: *wordpress
    image: wordpress:cli

volumes:
  wp_root:
    driver_opts:
      type: tmpfs
      device: tmpfs
  db_data:
```